# can javascript access the same data as internal chrome pages

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am wondering if a javascript script, can access the same level of data as pages contained in the chrome://urls section. I was looking at the pages, and saw that they source out to a resources javascript file.

I also found snippets of code like this

```
/*
 * Called by gpu c++ code when client info is ready.
 */
onCallAsyncReply: function(requestId, args) {
  if (this.pendingCallbacks_[requestId] === undefined) {
    throw new Error('requestId ' + requestId + ' is not pending');
  }
  var callback = this.pendingCallbacks_[requestId];
  callback(args);
  delete this.pendingCallbacks_[requestId];
},
```

I would like to know if a javscript plugin could access this data from the internal pages with user permission.

Comment: I don't think so. Those are used by chrome internally to handle a lot of stuff (managing filesystem, managing cache, ... all sort of things). If they let you access those using javascript then Chrome will become a huge wormhole for malecious attacks.

Comment: I dont believe they can be directly accessed, or interacted with, but i would like to know if the data can be retrieved.

Comment: what  data?........................

Comment: When you go to chrome://urls you are shown several urls, i know that these sites run javascript, but can i use a src tag to access the resources, or is thier some other method of accessing something like wifi, or is this impossible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They cannot be accessed, they judt communicate with a C program and get data, I say this because you cannot mark a comment as an answer, and i read more of the javascript.